# powerapp: add in-app camera picture to attachment

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

Powerapps:
Is it possible to add a picture taken by the in-app camera to an attachment control?

If I take the picture and add it to the same collection as used in the attachment control (using collect) the collection gets overridden and is only filled with the newly taken picture.

Collect(MyPictures;({Name:"pic1.jpg";Url:Camera1.Photo})

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo in your statement above and suspect that is the issue. You have a semi-colon after "MyPictures". Change it to a comma. Interestingly that is not a syntax error so maybe that is what the issue is i.e. no pictures are being captures and you feel like it is replacing the image?

I also tried the functionality myself and am able to capture multiple pictures.